# Flatpickr and Moment.js unexpected date format

Tags: date, datetime, timestamp, momentjs, flatpickr

I'm using the following instantiation code for Flatpickr.

```
$("#entry_date_time").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"),
    dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",
    minuteIncrement: 1
});
```

The issue I'm having is that `moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");` gives me the right data but the output of `$("#entry_date_time").val()` is equal to

> 2017201720172017-JanJan-SatSat 0000:JanJan:0000

instead of the expected format I provided.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this would be great, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output, and looking at the flatpickr docs for [date](http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/e/58307/demo.html#dateformat) and [time](http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/e/58307/demo.html#timeformat), it seems that only single characters are expected in the format instead of multiple ?  For example, the 4 Y's would explain the year being repeated 4 times, the month twice, etc.

The dateFormat that you need should probably be:

```
dateFormat: "Y-M-D H:i"
```

...however, I do **NOT** see a formatting option for the seconds portion of the time by flatpickr?

**Update on the seconds**:

There is a [flatpickr feature request](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr/issues/101) for the seconds capability.

Answer (score 5):

Flatpickr has its own [formating tokens](https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/) that are different from the ones supported by moment. But the good thing is you can use `parseDate` and `formatDate` config options to support custom formatting tokens.

```
/* A custom datestring parser */
parseDate: (date: string, format: string) => Date;

/* Allows using a custom date formatting function instead of the built-in. Generally unnecessary.  */
formatDate: (date: Date, format: string, locale: Locale) => string;
```

**Example with moment.js compatible tokens**
https://jsfiddle.net/armujahid/pwqhznj0/

```
const fp = flatpickr(".date", {
  altInput: true,
  dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  altFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY",
  allowInput: true,
  parseDate: (datestr, format) => {
    return moment(datestr, format, true).toDate();
  },
  formatDate: (date, format, locale) => {
    // locale can also be used
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
});
```

**Reference:** my comment at https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/1549#issuecomment-537939826

**Update:** this snippet has also been added in [official docs](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#custom-parsing-and-formating)